# returning matching elements using MongoDB 4.0 find function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nested, find

Mongodb returns non-matching elements in nested array

Here's my database sample:

```
  const users = [{
        'username':'jack',
        'songs':[{
            'song':'Another Love',
            'likes':false
        }, {
            'song':"i'm into you",
            'likes': true
        }]
    }, {
        'username':'Stromae',
        'songs':[{
            'song':'Take me to church',
            'likes':false
        }, {
            'song':"Habits",
            'likes': true
        }]
    }];
```

I'm trying to find the following row:

```
 const query = {'username':'Stromae' , 'songs.song':'Take me to church','songs.likes':true};
 const result = await usersTable.find(query).project({'songs.$':1}).toArray();
```

as you see I'm trying to find a user who called "Stromae" and has a "Take me to church" song and he don't like it.

I'm expecting as result to be null, while the result is:

```
{ _id: 5d302809e734acbc5ffa2a8f,
  songs: [ { song: 'Take me to church', likes: false } ] }
```

as you see from the result it ignores that I need "likes" field to be true.

Comment: The `find()` is empty, you do not actually use the query.

Comment: Sorry, it's just in here, I was trying to make the code readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you are trying to match data from 'songs' array which satisfying both the conditions for the 'song' and 'likes' both fields. But you haven't provided the logic like check both the fields for same array element. That's why it is checking this fields in whole 'songs' array.

To check condition for single array element you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and for checking both the conditions are satisfying or not use the [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator.

You can use your Mongo query as:

```
db.usersTable.find({
  "username": "Stromae",
  songs: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $and: [
        {
          "song": "Take me to church"
        },
        {
          "likes": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Just update your 'find' query, you might get your required result.

Comment: I think I have tried the following, but I will try again and leave you my result

Comment: Yeah it working, what if I would like to match only the songs without the username, can I just remove it and how?

Comment: Yes, by removing `"username": "Stromae"` field from 'find' query you can just apply the 'songs' field check in your query.